# replace elements of array in python

Tags: python, arrays, threshold

I can't correctly change the elements of arrays with slicing in python
please help me!!

this is my code:

```
maxVal=np.max(gradIntensity2) 
thrGradIntensity=gradIntensity2.copy()
highThr=maxVal/5
lowThr=maxVal/40
indHT=np.argwhere(gradIntensity2>=(highThr))
indLT=np.argwhere(gradIntensity2<=(lowThr))
ind1=(lowThr)<gradIntensity2
ind2=gradIntensity2<(highThr)
ind3=ind1 & ind2
ind=np.argwhere(ind3)
thrGradIntensity[indHT]=1
thrGradIntensity[indLT]=0
thrGradIntensity[ind]=0.5
print(maxVal) #-----------------------------result= 425.9426808716647
print(highThr)#-----------------------------result= 85.18853617433294
print(lowThr) #------------------------------result= 10.648567021791617
print(np.max(thrGradIntensity)) #--------------result= 0.5
print((thrGradIntensity==0.5).all()) #---------------result= true
```

I expect that
`np.max(thrGradIntensity) == 1` but this doesn't happen
why?????
`print((thrGradIntensity==0.5).all())` why is this true?!
my thresholding isn't work.

Comment: Maybe it depends on what `gradIntensity2` is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How slicing in Python works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works)

Comment: Is `gradIntensity2` 1-dimensional? Try to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (especially a sample `gradIntensity2`) and show it as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @Meuko The linked question refers to slicing in the standard library while the question here is about numpy, therefore they aren't related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using np.argwhere as indices for a 2D array will treat each coordinate pair as a pair of row indices, not (row, column).

Example:

```
test = np.array([[1, 2],
                [3, 4]])

where_3 = np.argwhere(test == 3)

print(where_3)
print(test[where_3])
```

Output:

```
[[1 0]]
[[[3 4]
  [1 2]]]
```

It correctly identifies [1, 0] as the correct indices, but using `test[where_3]` returns the 1-row and the 0-row.

You're better off just dropping the np.argwhere and just using the boolean masks.

```
maxVal=np.max(gradIntensity2) 
thrGradIntensity=gradIntensity2.copy()
highThr=maxVal/5
lowThr=maxVal/40
indHT=gradIntensity2>=(highThr)
indLT=gradIntensity2<=(lowThr)
ind1=(lowThr)<gradIntensity2
ind2=gradIntensity2<(highThr)
ind = ind1 & ind2
thrGradIntensity[indHT]=1
thrGradIntensity[indLT]=0
thrGradIntensity[ind]=0.5
print(maxVal) #-----------------------------result= 425.9426808716647
print(highThr)#-----------------------------result= 85.18853617433294
print(lowThr) #------------------------------result= 10.648567021791617
print(np.max(thrGradIntensity)) #--------------result= 0.5
print((thrGradIntensity==0.5).all()) #---------------result= true
```

Comment: Additionally, the documentation for [np.argwhere](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) explicitly states "The output of argwhere is not suitable for indexing arrays. For this purpose use [nonzero(a)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) instead."